# split excel sheet for every nrows using python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with more than 1 million rows. Now i need to split that for every n rows  and save it in a new file. am very new to python. Any help, is much appreciated and needed

Comment: Save your excel document as a csv and read the csv module documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.

Comment: Hope this api helps  https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I have already tried that, the excel files are so large that while trying to convert them into csv file they get struck for long time.that is why am trying to split excel sheet into smaller multiple excels so that i can convert them into csv and read them into mysql using python

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by OhAuth you can save the Excel document to a `csv` file. That would be a good start to begin the processing of you data.

Processing your data you can use the Python [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). That would not require any installation since it comes with Python automatically.

If you want something more "powerful" you might want to look into [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). However, that requires an installation of the module.

If you do not want to use the `csv` module of Python nor the `pandas` module because you do not want to read into the docs, you could also do something like.

```
f = open("myCSVfile", "r")
for row in f:
    singleRow = row.split(",") #replace the "," with the delimiter you chose to seperate your columns
    print singleRow
    > [value1, value2, value3, ...] #it returns a list and list comprehension is well documented and easy to understand, thus, further processing wont be difficult
```

However, I strongly recommend looking into the moduls since they handle `csv` data better, more efficient and on 'the long shot' save you time and trouble.

Comment: I have already tried that, the excel files are so large that while trying to convert them into csv file they get struck for long time.that is why am trying to split excel sheet into smaller multiple excels so that i can convert them into csv and read them into mysql using python

Comment: @SailendraVarma If you just want to create for each row a new file, there is no need to take the detour over mysql. You can do that from the csv file! If you have problems converting the Excel into csv, look into the modul JLILI posted. But making a csv, reading it into mysql and then reading it out of mysql to create a file for n rows does not makes sense...

Comment: u didn't get my requirement.I don't need to split excel for every row and create a new excel file for that.Will defntly look into the csv module

Comment: @SailendraVarma Sorry. You might want to edit your question then. If you like the hints, please upvote or accept answere :)